# Is it possible to use mathematica to find the derivative of a function with respect to some "ax" where "a" is a constant?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica evaluates the derivative of most complicated functions within a fraction of second. But while doing analysis sometimes we might be in a situation to differentiate or integrate a function with respect to some "ax" instead of "x" so in these cases is it possible to find the derivative of the function with respect to "ax" where "a" is a constant.
For instance the fractional operators have the scaling property that:

$\frac{d^q f(ax)}{dx^q} = a^q \left(\frac{d^qf(ax)}{d(ax)^q}\right)$

Comment: It would help if you could supply a simple example of a function you want to take the derivative of, and what the expected output is.

Comment: I modified your example to try and make it easier to read. If you feel I changed the meaning of your question, please feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 3):

Half of this problem can be solved by using `Dt`. `Dt` calculates total derivatives, and ratios between total derivatives are derivatives in terms of functions. As a simple example, compare derivation by substitution of `Cosh[(a x^2+b)^2]` by `(a x^2+b)`:

```
D[Cosh[u^2], u] /. u -> a x^2 + b
```

> 2 (b + a x^2) Sinh[(b + a x^2)^2]

This should be an unsurprising result.

With `Dt`, however, this computation can be performed equivalently by:

```
Dt[Cosh[(a x^2 + b)^2], Constants -> {a, b}]/Dt[a x^2 + b, Constants -> {a, b}]
```

> 2 (b + a x^2) Sinh[(b + a x^2)^2]

Simply by changing the bottom ratio, the derivative by `Dt[a x, Constants -> {a, b}]` can also be found. That is left as an exercise to the reader.

Unfortunately, for integration, this is rather more difficult. There is no corresponding concept of a "total antiderivative". However, `DSolve` can handle some expressions with `Dt`, and may be able to help integrate them.

The main limitation with `DSolve` in this respect is that it requires the declaration of a dependent and independent variable, and the dependent variable can only depend on the independent variable explicitly. The typical formula for such an integration is something like:

```
DSolve[g'[x] == Dt[f[a x],Constants->a]/Dt[a x, Constants->a], g, x]
```

> {{g -> Function[{x}, C[1] + f[a x]/a}}

While this example is obviously no different than `DSolve[g'[x] == f'[a x], g, x]`, for more complex expressions it can be a simpler way to write the question:

```
DSolve[g'[x] == Dt[f[a x],Constants->a]/Dt[a x^2, Constants->a], g, x]
```

> {{g -> Function[{x}, C[1] + Integrate[f'[a K[1]]/(2 K[1]), {K[1], 1, x}]}}

Even so, the answer may be more complex than initially anticipated. The `K[1]` here is an automatically generated variable created by `DSolve` used up in the integration.

Comment: "That is left as an exercise to the reader." This is not a textbook.

Comment: @ciao Apologies for that, but due to the comparative complexity of the issue and limited time when I first wrote this answer, I figured a partial answer could be of more use than no answer at all. My intention was primarily to provide at least a hint as to the direction that could be taken. I have provided some examples now.